# c# DotLiquid filter truncatewords not working

Tags: filter, dotliquid

### Problem

This example doesn't work. It returns all five words.

```
{%assign value = "word word word word word"%}
{{ value | truncatewords: 1 }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

Instead use an underscore "truncate_words". This returns just one word.

```
{%assign value = "word word word word word"%}
{{ value | truncate_words: 1 }}
```

### Solution 2

If the namingconvention is set to C# than you should use camelcasing "TruncateWords". This returns just one word.

```
{%assign value = "word word word word word"%}
{{ value | TruncateWords: 1 }}
```